# How can I assign a model to all users upon creation in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have this model:

models.py

```
    class Upload_model(models.Model):
        content=models.CharField(max_length=200)
        user_name=models.ForeignKey(User)
```

forms.py

```
class upload_form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Upload_model
        fields=[“content”]
```

views.py

I'm trying to write a function that iterates the creation of the Upload_model to all Users independently. But it won't work.

```
def upload_all_user_models(request):
    if request.method==”POST”:
        form=upload_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        instance=form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user_name=User.objects.all()
        return redirect(“upload_all_user_models”)
    else:
        form=upload_form()
    return render(request,”uploadpage.html”,{“form”:form})
```

I want the Upload_model to be assigned to all users upon creation but I seem to be getting a ValueError. How can I solve this?

Comment: not sure if that's the real issue, but : ```user_name=models.ForiegnKey(User)```

You mistyped ForeignKey

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you use `instance.user_name=User.objects.all()`, you're assigning the `instance.user_name` to a queryset of User rather than each individual users (i.e. `instance.user_name=[queryset<id=1, id=2>]`). You need to set up conditional statements that determine if each user doesn't have the Upload_model, then add and save Upload_model to the user.

What you're trying to create is going to be complicated due to the order in which model gets created first: the upload_model or the user.

Let's say you have 5 users and you create an Upload_model, saving the Upload_model to the 5 users. What's going to happen if user #6 comes along?

I'm sure there's a way you can configure the code to make it how you want it, but at the end of it all, your question is quite vague but all in all you're getting a ValueError because you're trying to assign user_name not to each user, but to a list of users.